# dynamic tree menu using awesome nested set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how do you create a dynamic tree menu helper using awesome nested set (or any other set plugin) in rails ? the result should look something like this:

```
<div class="level_0">
  <span class="title">Categroy</span>
  <div class="level_1>
    <span class="title">SubCategroy</span>

    <div class="level_2>
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
    </div>

    <span class="title">SubCategroy</span>

    <div class="level_2>
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="level_1>
    <span class="title">SubCategroy</span>

    <div class="level_2>
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
    </div>

    <span class="title">SubCategroy</span>

    <div class="level_2>
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
      SubSubcategory
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make something similar to what you describe following this:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation